# How to stop PHPUnit from adding included/required files as part of the testsuite?

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, testcase

I tried to follow the PHPUnit manual on how to setup a testsuite with a custom test execution order. I now realized that i only need these lines and some includes to get the suite working:

```
public static function suite()
{
    $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('Package');
    return $suite;
}
```

But when i use the above lines the test execution order is defined by the sort order of my includes. And when i try to change it via suite() as followes the tests are executed twice, first in the sort order as defined by suite() and after that in the sort order of the includes:

```
public static function suite()
{
    $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('Package');
    $suite->addTestSuite('Package_Class1Test');
    $suite->addTestSuite('Package_Class2Test');
    $suite->addTestSuite('Package_Class3Test');
    return $suite;
}
```

Includes are done by:

```
require_once 'Package/Class3Test.php';
require_once 'Package/Class2Test.php';
require_once 'Package/Class1Test.php';
```

Result (test execution order):

```
1) Class1Test
2) Class2Test
3) Class3Test
4) Class3Test
5) Class2Test
6) Class1Test
```

I am using Netbeans 7.0beta to run the PHP 5.3.5 / PHPUnit 3.5.11 on windows 7.
I read the phpunit manual (http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.5/en/organizing-tests.html) but i have no clue what i am doing wrong...

Please help.

PS: This problem can be solved by autoloading the classes.

Comment: Well stated question, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

PHPUnit 3.5 was released five years ago and has not been supported for four years. But even five years ago using `PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite` objects to compose a test suite was no longer considered a good practice.

Please read the [Getting Started](https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html) article on the PHPUnit website as well as the chapter on [organizing tests](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html) in the PHPUnit manual to learn how to properly organize your test suite.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, Sebastian. Defining the suite in the xml file with explicit file order will work fine for me after having rethought the shared fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling `phpunit` with the right parameters?

I have this setup, which works fine with suites.

```
/tests/
/tests/allTests.php
/tests/lib/
/tests/lib/libAllTests.php
/tests/lib/baseTest.php
/tests/lib/coreTest.php
/tests/lib/...
```

**allTests.php:**

```
require_once 'lib/libAllTests.php';
class AllTests
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('Project'); 
        $suite->addTestSuite('LibAllTests');     
        return $suite;
    }
}
```

**libAllTests.php:**

```
require_once 'baseTest.php';
require_once 'coreTest.php';    
class LibAllTests
{
    public static function suite()
    {
        $suite = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite('Lib'); 
        $suite->addTestSuite('CoreTest');
        $suite->addTestSuite('BaseTest'); 
        return $suite;
    }
}
```

From a command prompt I can call:

- `phpunit /tests/allTests.php`: Runs all tests
- `phpunit /tests/lib/libAllTests.php`: Runs all lib tests
- `phpunit /tests/lib/baseTest.php`: Runs all base tests
- `phpunit /tests/*`: Runs all tests

And in all four scenarios, the core tests are run before base tests, and no tests are repeated twice.

I'm using phpUnit 3.5.7.

Comment: We don't use suite files, and we can still run all tests for a subdirectory tree using e.g. `phpunit /tests/lib`. We have the advantage that tests can run in any order. Are there other advantages to using hand-created test suites? How do you make sure you don't forget to add a new test?

Comment: Hi. Only two reason to use suites (in my experience); (1) if you want the tests executed in a specific order and (2) you can have a suite setUp/tearDown affecting all included tests. In regard to remembering newly added tests, I haven't got a fix solution.